# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WEB-INF/classes/

Tags: java, weblogic

I am getting an error when deploying an **EAR** file which contains a web service and a web application.  I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when I deploy the application because the server is looking in the wrong folder for the class file.

The server (WebLogic) thinks the class file should be in `WEB-INF/classes`, but it is in `<project-root>/classes`.

How do I change where WebLogic should look for class files?  I already tried the classpath, doesn't work.

Comment: Your EAR is broken.  Put files in their correct locations according to the spec.

Comment: Is that the complete exception trace? I doubt it. Would be better if you post the complete one.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because this is the structure of the web application according to the specification. Check this out: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html